# Create array of javascript wrapped objects in C++

Tags: node.js, v8

I am using NAN and `ObjectWrap` and want to create a list of wrapped objects and return it from a static function.  What I'm doing is using a class to represent a window and enumerating the top-level windows in Windows 10.  Here's what I have for the new method for creating an object in Javascript (which calls the default MWindowMapper constructor which calls the default MWindow constructor which uses the foreground window):

```
static NAN_METHOD(NewMethod) {
    MWindowWrapper* obj = new MWindowWrapper();
    obj->Wrap(info.This());
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(info.This());
}
```

So what can I use in place of `info.This()` to create a new wrapped object using my MWindowWrapper class?  The start of my `MWindowWrapper` class looks like this:

```
static Nan::Persistent<FunctionTemplate> constructor;

class MWindowWrapper : public Nan::ObjectWrap {
public:
    static NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init) {
        Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = New<FunctionTemplate>(MWindowWrapper::NewMethod);
        constructor.Reset(tpl);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following:

1. get the function template from the persistent variable
2. get the function from the template
3. call `NewInstance()` on the constructor using `isolate->GetCurrentContext()` from my function call
4. use `ToLocalChecked()` on the `MaybeLocal<Object>` returned

Then I could wrap the object and return it.

```
// get FunctionTemplate from persistent object
Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = Nan::New(constructorTemplate);

// get function from template
Local<Function> cons = tpl->GetFunction();

// create new instance in the current context
v8::MaybeLocal<Object> instance = cons->NewInstance(
    isolate->GetCurrentContext(), 0, nullptr);

// use as Local<Object>
Local<Object> obj = instance.ToLocalChecked();

// now wrap object and return
MWindowWrapper* w = new MWindowWrapper();
w->Wrap(obj);
info.GetReturnValue().Set(obj);
```